# Does pasteurization count as cooking in prep of juices for after noon?

Tags: food, precept

If I were to have, lets say, a V8 after noon, and it was not cooked... but was pasteurized (heated at a high temp which is considered by the food industry to not be a temperature sufficient to cause it to actually cook... like just under the boiling point)... would this be in keeping with the 6th precept as a daily practice. Like during 7pm tea for example.

I am obviously running under the notion that raw pulp-free vegetable or fruit juice is 100% allowable which was told to me by a monk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Heating juice is allowed; cooking it is not:

> “I allow reheating.”
>
> Mv.VI.17.6

Comment: cool, thanks bhante... great interview this morning!

Answer (score 1):

For bhikkhus, Some vegetables are not allowable.  Better to do juice and mix with cool water.  The BMC says boiled juices are sugar.  This is only Thai Tradition.
BMC will list the vegetables and fruits allowable.  Cucumber is not allowable.
Boiled juices are prohibited by paauk

Tea is actually not allowable as a "drink" for this reason of heating.  Leaf juice is allowable, but you cannot add boiling water.  Hence the rule of only warming by the sun's heat.  You should be "sick and have a reason" for any medicine.
This would outlaw, cold green tea. Aka Snapple.

Juice drinks or sugar mixed with water can be taken for any reason, including thirst.